# Magento 1.9 : How can I add a button in admin role edit form?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, permissions, user-roles, edit

I need a custom functionality "Duplicate Role" in

> Admin > System > Permissions > Roles > Edit.

How can I add an extra button in this form? 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please more elaborate your question?

Comment: At Magento Backend > System > Permissions > Role > Edit Form, I need to add an extra button called "Duplicate Role" other than "Back", "Delete Role", "Save Role".

Comment: Any updates here ?